# Editing header by adding "pipe" in fasta file

Tags: grep, header, editing, fasta

I want to edit my headers in fasta file by adding pipes but unable to do so. The header looks like this

> KX035646.1 Name:NADH domain
>   ATGCGGGGCTGC..

I want it like

> sp|KX035646.1| Name:NADH domain

The accession number is different for all sequences
Can you please help me doing it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a simple sed one liner:

```
cat test.fasta
>KX035646.1 Name:NADH domain ATGCGGGGCTGC..
ACGT
CTTT
>KX035646.2 Name:NADH domain ATGCGGGGCTGC..43214
GCAT

sed 's/^>\([a-zA-Z0-9.]\+\)\(.*\)/>sp|\1|\2/' test.fasta
>sp|KX035646.1| Name:NADH domain ATGCGGGGCTGC..
ACGT
CTTT
>sp|KX035646.2| Name:NADH domain ATGCGGGGCTGC..43214
GCAT
```